# Closed subscheme $Z$ of a scheme $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, schemes

Let us have $X$ a projective, smooth Calabi-Yau 3-fold and  $Z \subset X$ be a subscheme supported on curves and points.  Its structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{Z}$ fits into the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal{I}_{Z} \to \mathcal{O}_{X} \to \mathcal{O}_{Z} \to 0.$$

where $\mathcal{I}_Z$ is the ideal sheaf (supported on $Z$?) This is a generic statement but I do not quite understand it, or the information I can get from this.

What I understand, more diff. geometrically, is the following: *On $X$ we have the ring of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X$ and thus we have a corresponding sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. There exist submanifolds (subschemes in the language above) $Z$ whose ring of regular functions are $\mathcal{O}_Z$ which can be embedded (included?) in $X$ (I guess) as*
$$
\mathcal{O}_Z \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X
$$
So $Z$ could be 2 dimensional or 1 dimensional  0r 0 dimensional. Then over these submanifolds we have their local ring of functions forming a subring of the ring of functions of the whole space. **What is the role of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Z$ then?**

What I ask is a more *differential geometric* way to understand ideal sheaves supported on closed subschemes. If there is a vector bundle version of this story that would be even better (i.e. focus on locally free sheaves).

Any help with this intuition or reference would be great.

Comment: Surely $O_Z$ is not a subring, it is a quotient. The ideal sheaf, intuitively, contains the information about how $Z$ is cut in $X$. Actually, giving the ideal sheaf determines $O_Z$ (which is nothing but $O_X$ modulo the ideal sheaf). Reference: any book on algebraic geometry. If you want a differential geometric perspective, take a book that discusses GAGA, or coherent analytic sheaves.

Comment: Also note that ideal sheaves of closed subschemes are anything BUT supported on those subschemes.

Comment: @TabesBridges yes, I understand it now I think. Indeed, you are absolutely right. I can write $\mathcal{O}_Z = \mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}_Z$ therefore this is obviously showing that ideal sheaves have absolutely no support on $Z$.